# Suddenly TMP files cannot be renamed by Zend or other PHP programs

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-web-services, zend

We have several virtual servers utilizing Zend Framework 2.  Suddenly, we are getting errors when the applications are trying to rename TMP files to their permanent locations.

Here is an example of the error messages:

```
Message:
File '/tmp/php4i88d1' could not be renamed. An error occurred while processing the file.
Stack trace:
#0 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/File/RenameUpload.php(194): Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload->moveUploadedFile('/tmp/php4i88d1', 'public/uploads/...')
#1 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/AbstractFilter.php(89): Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload->filter(Array)
#2 [internal function]: Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter->__invoke(Array)
#3 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/FilterChain.php(225): call_user_func(Object(Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload), Array)
#4 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/FileInput.php(70): Zend\Filter\FilterChain->filter(Array)
#5 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/BaseInputFilter.php(406): Zend\InputFilter\FileInput->getValue()
#6 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Form.php(355): Zend\InputFilter\BaseInputFilter->getValues()
#7 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Form.php(516): Zend\Form\Form->bindValues()
#8 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Admin/src/Admin/Controller/TemplateController.php(193): Zend\Form\Form->isValid()
#9 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Admin\Controller\TemplateController->editTemplateAction()
#10 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#17 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#18 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#19 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/public/index.php(23): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#20 {main}
Previous exceptions:
ErrorException
File:
/part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/File/RenameUpload.php:216
Message:
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php4i88d1' to 'public/uploads/templatedocumentmaster/11ff5789fdd6c52e860f2e12aba90c17.jpg'
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Zend\Stdlib\ErrorHandler::addError(2, 'move_uploaded_f...', '/part2/sites/be...', 216, Array)
#1 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/File/RenameUpload.php(216): move_uploaded_file('/tmp/php4i88d1', 'public/uploads/...')
#2 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/File/RenameUpload.php(194): Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload->moveUploadedFile('/tmp/php4i88d1', 'public/uploads/...')
#3 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/AbstractFilter.php(89): Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload->filter(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter->__invoke(Array)
#5 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/FilterChain.php(225): call_user_func(Object(Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload), Array)
#6 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/FileInput.php(70): Zend\Filter\FilterChain->filter(Array)
#7 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/BaseInputFilter.php(406): Zend\InputFilter\FileInput->getValue()
#8 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Form.php(355): Zend\InputFilter\BaseInputFilter->getValues()
#9 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Form.php(516): Zend\Form\Form->bindValues()
#10 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Admin/src/Admin/Controller/TemplateController.php(193): Zend\Form\Form->isValid()
#11 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Admin\Controller\TemplateController->editTemplateAction()
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#18 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#19 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#20 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#21 /part2/sites/beta-ppa2/ZendSkeletonApplication/public/index.php(23): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

Any ideas on why this would suddenly happen?  We have had no updates to binaries or server files for more than two days - and these two SEPARATE applications were working fine since that time.  They are on the same server, but separate apps.

These are sites on AWS servers running Amazon linux ami's. And it should be noted that these same applications are working fine on the development servers. This is only occurring on the production server. Both the TMP directory and the destination directory have full permissions and proper ownership - nothing was changed there for months.

Thanks, in advance, for help!

Comment: Check your main server logs for any relevant messages. do basic filesystem check - is the disk full, does it have inodes etc ?

Comment: Did that.  Nothing in the server logs I could find that was relevant at all.  Only 14% inode usage on this drive.  Disk has 25% free.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  The partition is, indeed, full.  The readings we had of 25% free were incorrect - it is 100% full.

Silly that this is the answer.  But maybe this will help someone else.

Thanks to all who helped out!